# Accessing Visual Studio DTE members hangs when a modal dialog is opened in the IDE

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, freeze, envdte

In the below code, I am trying to access the `Debugger` property of a valid `DTE2` object (obtained through a method similar to [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2011/08/10/how-to-get-dte-from-visual-studio-process-id.aspx)), to check if it is debugging the current process (multiple Visual Studio instances may be opened).

It works well, except that when one of the Visual Studio (2015) instances is showing a modal dialog (for example asking if the source code of the currently loaded project should be reloaded due to background code changes), accessing `dte.Debugger` will hang until the dialog is dealt with by the user. Trying to access other members of the `dte` object will also hang.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
using System.Threading;
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;
using EnvDTE90a;

public static class VSAutomation {
  public static int? GetCurrentDebuggerPid() {
    var taskCompletion = new TaskCompletionSource<int?>();
    var staThread = new System.Threading.Thread(() => {
      try {
        int? debuggerPid = null;
        using (new MessageFilter()) {
          using (var currentProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess())
          using (var vsInstances = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("devenv").AsDisposable()) {
            foreach (var p in vsInstances.Enumerable) {
              DTE2 dte;
              if (TryGetVSInstance(p.Id, out dte)) {
                Utils.Retry(() => {
                  var debugger = dte.Debugger; //MAY HANG HERE
                  if (debugger != null) {
                    foreach (Process2 process in debugger.DebuggedProcesses) {
                      if (process.ProcessID == currentProcess.Id) {
                        debuggerPid = p.Id;
                        break;
                      }
                    }
                  }
                  Marshal.ReleaseComObject(dte);
                }, nbRetries: int.MaxValue, msInterval: 1000, retryOnlyOnExceptionTypes: typeof(COMException).InArray());
                if (debuggerPid != null) break;
              }
            }
          }
        }
        taskCompletion.SetResult(debuggerPid);
      }
      catch (Exception ex) {
        taskCompletion.TrySetException(ex);
      }
    }) { IsBackground = true };
    staThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    staThread.Start();
    taskCompletion.Task.Wait();
    return taskCompletion.Task.Result;
  }
}
```

Is there any way to access the `Debugger` object despite the modal dialog box being opened?

If not, is there any way to detect that a user action is required, apart from launching the assignment `var debugger = dte.Debugger` in a task with a timeout?

Comment: Hey, did you ever manage to resolve this? I have a similar issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56700937/respond-to-dialog-boxes-using-dte-executecommand

Comment: @SyntaxError No, I didn't unfortunately.

Comment: @SyntaxError You really need to update to VS 2019 if possible, they did make a lot of improvements.

Comment: I do have both versions concurrently but am still working with some older projects that won't (yet) build in VS2019