# Respond to dialog boxes using DTE.ExecuteCommand

Tags: c#, visual-studio, envdte

Is there a way to say `Yes` or `No` or `OK` to a dialog/message box while opening Visual Studio 2015 using `EnvDTE`?

I've tried debugging my application while the box is open but I have no idea what to look for. I've also tried searching within [this list of commands](https://github.com/ligershark/VoiceExtension/blob/master/src/Resources/commands.txt) but cannot find anything that responds to a message box.

I am using code based on this [Microsoft guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ms228772(v=vs.100)) to open an instance of Visual Studio, open a solution and then run commands against it.

The messages that come up upon opening my solution are related to TFS. My application works otherwise, but cannot get past these dialog boxes to execute commands. The first one says this:

> Team Foundation Server Version Control
>   The solution you are opening is bound to source control on the following team foundation server: . Would you like to contact this server to enable source control integration?
>   `yes` `no` `help`

I want to press `No`

Then I see this box, which I need to press `OK` on 3 times.

[image: TFS Error box]